# ESC-q doesn't work in tmux with zsh

Tags: zsh, tmux, escape-characters

I use <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> a lot (stashing the current line while I execute another command), and it works fine with Gnome Terminal 3.6.0 + zsh. However, if I start `tmux`, then it stops working: the cursor just moves one character to the left and stays there. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> does not work either.

I don't set `TERM` in .zshrc, in `.tmux.conf` I use: `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"`.

Comment: Does it work as Alt-q?

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution for myself (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>q</kbd>)

```
bindkey "^[q" push-line
```

I got that `"^["` part from the `zkbd` script (see `man zshcontrib`). You probably can get the equivalent for the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key there, but it looks to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because `tmux` decides it is an escape sequence that ought to match one of the keys defined in your terminal description (terminfo), but fails to find a match and discards it.